# my div is not expanding to screen size and picture in div is therefore not stuck to footer

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where I use 1 div and in this one i have 2 divs.

```
<div id="bigdiv">
<div id="leftdiv"></div>
<div id="rightdiv"></div>
</div>
```

They are sharing the page and therefore in css the left one has float left and the other one float right and alos the sizes.

CSS looks like this

```
#biddiv { width: 100%; height: 100%;)
#leftdiv { width: 50%; height: 100%; float: Left;}
#rightdiv { width: 50%; height: 100%; float: Right;}
```

and here comes my problem. The left div has a picture in it and when i resize the webpage the left div will stop adjusting its height and will therefore leave a white blank area down to the footer. This is not something the right div does.

the pictures css looks like this:

```
#picture {height:100%; width:100%; }
```

Using position:absolut or something like that dont work beacuse then the picture goes crazy and places itself anywhere even outside the div its in.

How can i make the div adjust the height and make the picure stay at the footer? The right div adjusts itself and is stuck to the footer why not the left one?

Comment: Please provide a working example of your problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ucpbdfrv/